# How to permanently check in files into Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, clearcase

I'm using Clearcase for source control, and when I right-click on my solution file, there's an option for checking in the files.
Trouble is that immediately after checking in the files, it automatically does a check-out.

How do I keep the files checked in for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an option in Visual Studio to prevent an "auto-checkout" after checkins.
However, check also the exact version of ClearCase you are using, because [other bugs around checkout/chekin files also exist](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21398977).

---

Sure enough, the [OP Nav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453673/nav) reports in the comment:

> The checkbox is in:
>   **`Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment > Keep items checked out when checking in`**

You can see the setting in [this article](http://tfsvc.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/checkoutscheck-ins-checkoutcheckin-settings/) (which was for Team Foundation Server, but which is still relevant for this particular question)

[image: settings]

Comment: Found it. Thanks. The checkbox is in Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment > Keep items checked out when checking in

Comment: @Nav: Excellent. I have included your feedback in the answer for more visibility.